# Oracle SQL Trigger Error- OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO: ORA-24344

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using a trigger called "users_id_trigger" to auto increment the users.user_id column.

But in Object Browser its status is showing invalid!
[image]

I am working on a PHP project where i am getting this error while i run the query from a PHP script. here is the error message:

> oci_execute(): OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO: ORA-24344: success with compilation error

Here is my method to create the entire table and related SEQUENCE and TRIGGER to be able to have auto increment feature in the user_id column.

```
public function create_users_table()
{
    // creating users table
    oci_execute(oci_parse($this->conn, "CREATE TABLE users(
        user_id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
        user_name VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
        user_password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        user_email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        user_location VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT users_pk PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
    )"));
    // creating users sequence
    oci_execute(oci_parse($this->conn, "CREATE SEQUENCE users_seq
        MINVALUE 1 
        START WITH 1 
        INCREMENT BY 1 
        NOCACHE;
    "));
    // creating user sequence trigger
    echo oci_execute(oci_parse($this->conn, "CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER users_id_trigger
        BEFORE INSERT ON users 
        FOR EACH ROW 
        BEGIN 
            :new.user_id := users_seq.nextval;
        END;
    "));
}
```

What i am doing wrong? because the table and sequence is created successfully but not the trigger.

**EDIT:**

while inserting a new row i got this error:

> insert into users values(1, 'hasan', '1234',
>   'hdg@live.com', 'Dhaka, Bangladesh')
>               * ERROR at line 1: ORA-04098: trigger 'FLIPLISTS.USERS_ID_TRIGGER' is invalid and failed re-validation

**Oracle Version i am using:** Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production (Windows 10)

**Compilation Error:** ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers

Comment: Yes, Windows 10 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

If oracle version that you are using is less than 11g then Modify your trigger as below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER users_id_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT ON users 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
        select users_seq.nextval into :new.user_id from dual ;
    END;
```

Comment: it also has the same error message:  oci_execute(): OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO: ORA-24344: success with compilation error

Comment: When it says "success with compilation error", please provide compilation error information.

Comment: Use a slash `/` in a newline after the `END;` in the creation sentence. Often a cause of compilation problems (I've faced that) and documentation always includes it.

Comment: Compilation Error: ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have newlines on windows,so remove them.

```
 echo oci_execute(oci_parse($this->conn, trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', "CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER users_id_trigger
        BEFORE INSERT ON users 
        FOR EACH ROW 
        BEGIN 
            :new.user_id := users_seq.nextval;
        END;
    "));));
```